# Remove LaTeX macro spanning multiple lines

Tags: python, latex, multiline

I have the following piece of LaTeX code and want to remove all occurences of \NEW{"text spanning multiple lines"}. The "text spanning multiple line" needs to be preserved and only "\NEW{" and somewhere in the file "}" needs to be removed, inside the new brackets should be left untouched. Tabs and spaces and newlines need to be preserved. I already tried to write a python application but could not produce decent output. The most difficult part is the place where you remove the brackets (and can be on the next line).

Input:

```
\chapter{A \NEW{very} small \NEW{chapter}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \NEW{Bla}
    \item Dusse
    \item Mekker
\end{itemize}

\NEW{This is new
    multiline \texttt{text} with some things \TBD{TBD} in between
  } The end
```

Output (expected):

```
\chapter{A very small chapter}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Bla
    \item Dusse
    \item Mekker
\end{itemize}

This is new
    multiline \texttt{text} with some things \TBD{TBD} in between
   The end
```

**Own solution in python which works:**

- Read line

  - Replace \NEW{ occurence with marker (char 0xff)
  - Read c in line

    - Check if c is marker, set marked = True, set marked_cnt for nested brackets, read next char
    - Else check: c == '{', increment marked_cnt
    - Else check: c == '}' and marked == True, decrement marked_cnt
    - If marked_cnt == -1, reset marked = False, marked_cnt = 0, read next char
    - Print "valid" char

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7
    import sys

    marker=chr(255)
    marked=False
    marked_cnt=0

    fin = open("file.tex", "r")
    fout = open("file.tex.out", "w")

    for line in fin:
        l = line.replace("\NEW{", marker)
        for c in l:
            if c == marker:
                marked = True
                marked_cnt = 0
                continue
            elif c == '{':
                marked_cnt += 1
            elif ((c == '}') and
                (marked == True)):
                marked_cnt -= 1

            if marked_cnt == -1:
                marked = False
                marked_cnt = 0
                continue

            fout.write(c)

    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

Comment: Is it required that the script should be in Python? If so, you might want to share what you did so far, so one can have a look at it and fix it!

Comment: If the only interest is for the output to be void of whatever the impact of `\NEW{..}` is, then you can set it to be a no-op: `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\NEW}{}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions:

```
import re
myRe = re.compile(r'\\NEW{\w+}')
for match in myRe.findall(myString):
    newstring = match.replace('\NEW{','')
    newstring = newstring.replace('}','')
    myString.replace(match,newstring)
```

This, however, won't get rid of the multi-line problem.  To solve that, go through the string directly, checking for then opening and closing of brackets:

```
while s.find('\\NEW{')>-1:
    position = s.find('\\NEW{')
    print(position, s[position:position+4])
    s = s[0:position]+s[position+5:]
    trailexist = True
    openbrackets = 0

    while trailexist and position<len(s):
        position +=1
        print(len(s), position,s[position])
        if s[position] == '}' and openbrackets == 0:
            s = s[:position]+s[position+1:]
            trailexist = False
            print("Removed!", position)
        elif s[position] == '{':
            openbrackets += 1
            print('Openbrackets:',openbrackets)
        elif s[position] == '}' and openbrackets>0:
            openbrackets -= 1
```